# How do you add HTML into an email in Blackberry?

Tags: html, email, blackberry, send, multipart

How do you add HTML into an email in Blackberry?

I've tried multipart emails, but that does not seem to work. I am asking how to send an HTML formatted email from an application running on a Blackberry, if I am wording too vaguely, please let me know how to rephrase my question

Comment: Can you please show what you actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

All HTML emails work the same way - the HTML is in the email body and any images must have a fully-qualified url (http://...).

CSS support is limited and must be defined inline statements (`style=""`) on each element (no stylesheets). Background images are not supported. Tables must be used for layouts (awful but true).

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about the HTML mailers, which are tricky and depend on the client Machine, where they will be eventually seen. Your HTML should be fully table layout based, Styles need to be inline. Below is an HTML mailer that is like almost perfect to display correctly on any device, whether it is MAC or PC or iPad or Blackberry.

http://www.dreamincode.net/iem/display.php?M=2016&C=f945ef50b90408df6b2eb3054df75e79&S=63&L=1&N=25

If you view the source of this page, you would come to know how the mailers need to be build out. 
To send the mailers as a mass mailing list you need an Email Marketing Software's.